# How to applicate android styles without change .java?

Tags: android, styles

My question is simple, I want to improve an android application using styles, so without change the *.java file…what I mean is use always “android.R.layout“ in the .java, but be allowed to change the appearance of spinner (and its options), the color of a textview, the background…etc

I’ve researched that defining styles.xml like this:

```
<resources>

    <style name="GreenHeader" >
        <item name="android:textColor">#04B404</item>
        <item name="android:typeface">normal</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">30pt</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    </style>

    <style name="RedHeader" parent="@style/GreenHeader" > 
        <item name="android:textColor">#FF0000</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

and calling

```
:android:theme="@style/RedHeader"
```

in the manifest.xml, when you use (for example) in the layout:

```
<Spinner
style= "@style/RedHeader"
```

something change…but it doesn’t works well, I don’t know what more I need, maybe some other xml file called themes…but I don’t know, I’ve found hours and hours without result
I need help to improve it, please!! Could anyone help me???

Answer (score 0):

Sorry you can not change styles programatically in android, but you can change a view or widget background programatically if it is enough for you.

Comment: Also you can inflate a xml file by using Layout inflator Button view = (Button) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.section_button, null)

Comment: that's what i want Yekmer Simsek, we are going to begin with an application but we want to implement it with styles, not defining the style of each buttom, editvew etc...how can i do it??thanksss

Comment: you should take a loot at themes documentation  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html